# Azure Pipline issue- ExcelDataReader Not found used by Specflow External Data Package

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, specflow, exceldatareader, external-data-source

I am using Specflow External Data for data input in my Specflow Tests.
I have my .xsl file as a DataSource for the Feature files located in the same Feature Folder. It is running fine on my local machine but when integrated to Azure DevOps Pipeline, it is failing with the error -

Error : Generation error: Message: Unable to load Excel file from 'D:\a\1\s\ConseroDemoProject\Feature\clients.xlsx': Could not load file or assembly 'ExcelDataReader, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 93517dbe6a4012fa'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The file is present in the repository on the same path and ExcelDataReader is also restored before the build. The build is failing on both Self Hosted and Microsoft Hosted Agents.
[This is pipeline log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn3wK.png)

Any Lead is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hello, did you manage to fix this? I have the same issue